# Can anyone please unblock my issue regarding selenium with python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
service_obj = Service("c:/user/GO40136258/downloads/chromedriver-win32")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service_obj)
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.programsbuzz.com')
```

output:

```
C:\Users\GO40136258\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe "C:\Users\GO40136258\Pycham project\DDP-automation\sample.py" 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\GO40136258\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\GO40136258\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 386, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\GO40136258\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1042, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\GO40136258\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 419, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\GO40136258\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 449, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\GO40136258\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 493, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\GO40136258\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 517, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\GO40136258\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 1075, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\GO40136258\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 1346, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\GO40136258\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 486, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\GO40136258\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 787, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\GO40136258\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 592, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='googlechromelabs.github.io', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /chrome-for-testing/latest-patch-versions-per-build.json (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\GO40136258\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\webdriver_manager\core\http.py", line 32, in get
    resp = requests.get(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\GO40136258\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 73, in get
    return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\GO40136258\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\GO40136258\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 589, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\GO40136258\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 703, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\GO40136258\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 517, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='googlechromelabs.github.io', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /chrome-for-testing/latest-patch-versions-per-build.json (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\GO40136258\Pycham project\DDP-automation\sample.py", line 5, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\GO40136258\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\webdriver_manager\chrome.py", line 40, in install
    driver_path = self._get_driver_binary_path(self.driver)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\GO40136258\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\webdriver_manager\core\manager.py", line 35, in _get_driver_binary_path
    binary_path = self._cache_manager.find_driver(driver)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\GO40136258\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\webdriver_manager\core\driver_cache.py", line 105, in find_driver
    driver_version = self.get_cache_key_driver_version(driver)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\GO40136258\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\webdriver_manager\core\driver_cache.py", line 152, in get_cache_key_driver_version
    return driver.get_driver_version_to_download()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\GO40136258\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\webdriver_manager\core\driver.py", line 48, in get_driver_version_to_download
    return self.get_latest_release_version()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\GO40136258\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\webdriver_manager\drivers\chrome.py", line 59, in get_latest_release_version
    response = self._http_client.get(url)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\GO40136258\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\webdriver_manager\core\http.py", line 35, in get
    raise exceptions.ConnectionError(f"Could not reach host. Are you offline?")
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: Could not reach host. Are you offline?

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Is there any alternative way to invoke the browser??

successfully Invoke the browser by using selenium with python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSL Certificate Verification Failed - When using WebDriverManager in Python Selenium framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69733766/ssl-certificate-verification-failed-when-using-webdrivermanager-in-python-sele)

Answer (score 0):

If you use the latest selenium version, then the most simplest approach to launch browser is using [Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/). Check the code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.quit()
```

Refer the below answer to know more about `SeleniumManager`

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774

Comment: i'm using selenium latest version. So i followed above code it's worked.
Thank you so much for quick response.

Comment: Glad it worked. Accept the answer so it’s not left un answered.